# Why does rootless podman does not support overlfayfs mounts in non-ubuntu distributions?

Tags: security, docker, overlayfs

In the [rootless podman doc](https://github.com/containers/libpod/blob/master/rootless.md), it is stated that:

> - Can not use overlayfs driver, but does support fuse-overlayfs
>
>   - Ubuntu supports non root overlay, but no other Linux distros do.

So overlayfs is not mountable in userspace in general, but ubuntu authorizes it, so it's not a technical difficulty (a setuid program could obviously do it).

So,

- Why is `overlayfs` in general not mountable from userspace?
- Why is not podman overriding this behavior to get an ubuntu-like behavior using a setuid program?